# How can I fetch paginated data recursively with promises?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm trying the fetch songs from a playlist recursively, but can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have a playlist object with an 'href' property. When I fetch the href, it returns an object with a property called 'tracks', which has a property called 'items'. One item in the 'items' represents one song. The playlist object also has a property called 'next', which is the href for the next page of songs.

With the following function I'm trying to log the array with all songs of a passed playlist object in the console, but it's not logging anything. Could someone show me how to do this task recursively? :)

```
const handleSelectPlaylist = (playlist) => {
setSelectedPlaylist(playlist)

const getSongs = (url = playlist.href, songs = []) => {
  fetch(url, {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken}
  }).then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    songs.push(data.tracks.items)
    if (data.tracks.next !== null) {
      getSongs(data.tracks.next, data)
    } else {
      console.log(songs)
    }
  })
}
return getSongs()
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're pretty close. But you're missing a return in your recursive call. A recursive function should either return data, or call itself again.

Let's refactor that into an async function, and also ensure that we use tail recursion.

```js
const handleSelectPlaylist = async (playlist) => {
  setSelectedPlaylist(playlist);

  const init = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accesstoken,
    },
  };

  // Use an async function, so that we can use await
  const getSongs = async (url, songs = []) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, init);
    const data = await response.json();

    songs.push(data.tracks.items);

    // If we've reached the end of the request, return the songs
    if (data.tracks.next === null) {
      return songs;
    }

    // Tail recursion call
    return await getSongs(data.tracks.next, songs);
  };

  const songs = await getSongs(playlist.tracks.href);

  console.log(songs);
};
```

Comment: @DSteman did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I'm getting the following error using your function: "Cannot read property 'items' of undefined". The data in the first iteration looks slightly different than in the iterations thereafter, so I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: I finally figured it out. The tail recursion call should have 'songs' as second argument instead of 'data'.

Comment: @DSteman ah yes, I see that. Thanks for updating the code snippet! Glad it worked out for you.